# Architecture Guidance Needed for Occasionally Connected Smart Client with MAUI

Tags: maui, smartclient, occasionallyconnected

I found this from 2016 which gives some broad strokes on Occasionally Connected Smart Clients: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10463 but given the date obviously does not cover MAUI. The service oriented approach seems best suited for multi-platform.

It mentions the The Smart Client Offline Application Block however the link to that block is dead and searches do not uncover any official Microsoft documentation.

Comment: @Jason I'm looking for architectural guidance

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  This is off-topic for multiple reasons